# List of all RGB combination (Python)

Tags: python, rgb

I want to make a list of lists.
These lists must contain all the combination (16 milion) of RGB palette.

Something like this:

```
all_colours = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3] ... [255,255,253],[255,255,254],[255,255,255]]
```

How can I achieve this ?

This is what I have actually, not so much...

```
rgb = []

for r in range(0, 256):
    rgb.append([r])

print(rgb)
```

Comment: Look up `itertools.combinations`. `rgb = list(combinations(range(256), 3))`

Comment: `itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3)`

Comment: `range(0xFFFFFF+1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

```
rgb = [[x,y,z] for x in range(256) for y in  range(256) for z in range(256)]
len(rgb) # 16777216 colors

# added square brackets to make all items lists inside main list
```

Comment: There are `16,777,216` possible rgb colors.  `range`'s max is not inclusive.

Comment: @chrisz, yeah, sorrry, my bad.. thanks for correction.

Comment: If I do [234, 76, 241]  (or any other values) in rgb it returns False

Comment: @Link, you can check (234, 76, 241) in rgb will be True, note that, elements inside rgb list are tuple, not list

Answer (score 0):

```
rgb = []

for r in range(0,256,1):
 for g in range(0,256,1):
  for b in range(0,256,1):
    rgb.append([r,g,b])

print(rgb)
```

This should work!

Comment: `.append` will be slow on 16mil records

Comment: You don't need to use `start` and `step` in range here, simply using `range(256)` will suffice.

Comment: Didn't know it would be slow, that's good to know! For range, I have a tendency to specify all the parameters. Maybe it's code paranoia.

Comment: This also works but BugHunter was faster.

Comment: Didn't even know you could do it like BugHunter did, learnt somethin new today.